# How do you "nest" or "group" Test::Unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

RSpec has:

```
describe "the user" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory :user
  end

  it "should have access" do
    @user.should ...
  end
end
```

How would you group tests like that with Test::Unit? For example, in my controller test, I want to test the controller when a user is signed in and when nobody is signed in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Test::Unit`, to my knowledge, does not support test contexts. However, [the gem `contest`](http://rubygems.org/gems/contest) adds support for context blocks.

Comment: In an attempt to save someone a 15 minutes of debugging, the contest gem is out of date and does not work with my Rails 4 application.

Comment: Gem doesn't work on Rails 5.2 either, see https://github.com/citrusbyte/contest/issues/9

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve something similar through classes. Probably someone will say this is horrible but it does allow you to separate tests within one file:

```
class MySuperTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "something general" do
    assert true
  end

  class MyMethodTests < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    setup do
      @variable = something
    end

    test "my method" do
      assert object.my_method
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Shoulda https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda although it looks like they've now made the context-related code into a separate gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context

Answer (score 2):

Using [`shoulda-context`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context):

In your Gemfile:

```rb
gem "shoulda-context"
```

And in your test files you can do things like (notice the `should` instead of `test`:

```rb
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  context 'Logged out user' do
    should "get current user" do
      get api_current_user_url

      assert_response :success
      assert_equal response.body, "{}"
    end
  end
end
```